# Is it possible to make object construction asynchronous?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have an `async` function that retrieve information from my webservice

```
private static async Task<DataClass> retrievData(){
...
}
```

And i need this information on my constructor, but i can't block the rest of my app

so i want to make something like

```
public class MyClass {
     private DataClass theData;
     public async Myclass(){
          var dataTemp = await Server.retrievData();
          if(dataTemp.ValidatorNumber == Server.Validator.FULL)
              theData = dataTemp
          ...
     }
```

but this is not allowed. Is there a work-around for this?

Comment: You can't. See stackoverflow.com/questions/8145479/can-constructors-be-async

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) blogpost.

Comment: i think i expressed wrong, i mean, how i workaround this ...

Comment: I re-phrased the question to ask for a way to construct an object asynchronously in the absence of `async` constructors. Since it is no longer a duplicate, I am voting to re-open it.

Comment: By putting that code in the constructor - you just make a bad design decision and everyone's life harder. The single responsibility of the constructor - is to construct an instance of an object. If you need to retrieve smth from a database - create a method for that with an appropriate name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot make a constructor `async`. However, you can make an `async` factory method:

```
public class MyClass {
    private DataClass theData;
    private Myclass(DataClass theData) {
        this.theData = theData;
    }
    public static async MyClass Create() {
        var dataTemp = await Server.retrievData();
        if(dataTemp.ValidatorNumber == Server.Validator.FULL)
              return new DataClass(dataTemp);
        ... // Deal with the error here
    }
}
```

Now the callers will have a way to make instances of `MyClass` asynchronously, like this:

```
var c = await MyClass.Create().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: I agree, this is a work-around, but design-wise - no, no,and no.

Comment: @SergeSemenov Mind explaining the reasons behind your "no-no" recommendation? I do not see anything particularly "heretical" with this approach, which boils down to constructing a wrapper for data obtained asynchronously.

Comment: 1. MyClass stronly coupled to Server. 2. Not testable. 3. Static is evil in most cases.

Comment: 1. Invert dependency with an interface. 2. You can create a mock of retrievData an inject to MyClass with an IoC container. 3. factory patten

Comment: @SergeSemenov So you object to the use of static factories in general, on philosophical grounds, as opposed to an `async` factory in this example, correct?

Comment: Let me just ask you to write a unit test for the static Create method (does not matter if it async or not). That should should explain why those design principles are important :)

Comment: @SergeSemenov OP already has a static factory method -  `Server.retrievData()`. My approach does not add a new static method, only replaces an existing static method for another static method.